# Kafka streams return all records where fieldx = some value

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I have records coming into kafka with multiple non-unique fields, lets call them Field1 ... Field n.

I want to write a query to return all of the records where fieldx = some value. Lets take the following simple example. Imagine that orders come into the system and one of the fields in an order is customerId. A basic operation would be to get all of the orders for a specific customer. How do I do this with Kafka Streams?

I already have a KTable and a materialized view of all the records, so I could just iterate through all of the records in the view and pick out the ones I want, but this seems like it would be inefficient and costly.

I would really like to create a materialized view where the view contained the records groupedby fieldx, but I don't see any way to do this. It looks like you can only use groupby with an aggregation, count, reduce, etc.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: You can remap the stream first to use the field your filtering as its key, so you can query for it when accessing the store.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `return all records`, but what about `stream.filter(...).to(...)` -- the filter can check each record for the condition you want (or maybe `stream.filter(...).foreach(...)`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should group your order stream on "customerID" and aggregate all the orders in a list. Result KTable will have `<CustomerId, [List of Order]>` types events.

Using Interactive queries, you can query the state store,

```
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
KStream<String, Order> orderStream = builder.stream("orders");
KTable<String,ArrayList<Order>> orderTable = orderStream
      .groupBy((key,value)-> value .get("customerId"))
      .aggregate(()-> new ArrayList<Order>(),
                 (key,val,agg)-> agg.add(val),
                  Materialized.as("customer-orders")
                  .withValueSerde(ArrayListSerde())          
       );
```

It will create a materialized view "customer-orders", which you can query via rest endpoint.

You can follow the below link for Exposing KTables as Rest Endpoint :

https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html

Comment: The problem of this approach might be, that the `List of Orders` may grow too large and exceed the maximum message size.

Comment: Agree, in order to handle that problem, OP needs to change the max.message.bytes or potentially change the keys for optimizing the list. I had the similar issue so had to make more details keys to reduce the list size.

Comment: I had to change the code in the answer a bit to make it work.
1. I had to add in Serialized.with for teh groupby so that it would de/serialize the orders correctly
2. ()-> new ArrayList<Order>() didn't work. What worked was
.aggregate(ArrayList::new,
                        (newKey,val,agg) -> {
                            agg.add(val);
                            return agg;
                        },

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for filtering orders by customer id. For this query, there is no need to create a KTable, for grouping or for aggregations. Yet since Kafka topics are append-only logs without secondary indexes, you really need to iterate through all messages to find the stream of orders matching your customer id.

```java
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
KStream<String, Order> orderStream = builder.stream("orders");
orderStream.filter((k,v) -> "customer-1".equals(v.customerId));
```

Note that the above code assumes that your stream of orders has also keys of type String, yet these keys are ignored.

Also note that you will need to specify how Kafka Streams should deserialize the messages into your Order class. You can specify deserializers using `Consumed.with(...)`.

For complete examples see the Kafka Streams Examples repository on github: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples

Not that these kinds of queries can also be written using KSQL: https://www.confluent.io/stream-processing-cookbook/

Comment: When/how would this code run? I have a REST API that gets a request for all orders for customerID = 3636. Would I then run the above code? Would this work more then once?

Comment: Seems like I misunderstood your question. If you are receiving multiple request for different customer ids, then indeed grouping  makes sense. Then you could use interactive queries for accessing the data in your state store.